# Data Validation that prevents user from entering any other character except a-z and spaces?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am creating a textbox in HTA where a user has to add his full name. But the problem is user can add name like "-hai_772". I just wants that user can use only alphabetical letters and he can use spaces within two words.

I tried the following, but it failed because I don't know how to set pattern for special all unwanted characters.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[Specialchrs,numeric-space]"
re.IgnoreCase =True
re.Global = True
hasMatches = re.Test(textbox.value)  
If hasMatches =True Then
  MsgBox "use letter"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for "known-bad" characters check if the input string contains any characters that are not "known-good":

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "[^a-z ]"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global     = True
If re.Test(textbox.value) Then
  MsgBox "use letters"
End If
```

By putting a caret (`^`) at the beginning of a character class (`[...]`) you invert the class (i.e. make it match characters that are not listed in the class). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for further information.

Even better than checking the input by script would be to define the allowed characters for your input field, so it doesn't accept other input in the first place:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" />
```